# Angular 2: Redirect to the right route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 models: AppModule, PanelModule.

in my AppComponent, I check if the user is logged in, and if he is, I redirect him to the panel. This is how I do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
      //If he is alredy logged, redirect him to the panel
      this.authService.login().subscribe(() => {
          this.authService.loaded = true;
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
          console.log("Navigating to panel..");
        this.router.navigate(['/panel']);
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem starts when my location is a child route. for example:

```
/panel/users
```

If I'm trying to access the URL directly, I navigate back to the `/panel` because the user is logged in and `this.router.navigate(['/panel']);` is executed.

What's the right approach so my app will redirect the user to the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably only want to subscribe to the first result:

```
this.authService.login().first().subscribe(() => {
```